# Android: From a popup window, how do I call a method in the object that initiated the popup window?

Tags: android, popup

I have an object "A"

"A" initiates the display of a popup window

That popup window has a button within it.

I want that button in the popup window to initiate a call to a method in "A".

I want to initiate the call from the line of code below that says:

"// RIGHT HERE I WANT TO CALL A METHOD IN "A" from which this popup was declared"

Generally speaking how can I call a method in the object that declares the popup window, from that popup window? this seems like it would be soo easy, but I am soo Newbie with this OO stuff.

If this explanation is confusing I will be happy to embellish.

```
public EventsOverlay A = new EventsOverlay(a, b))
class EventsOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

             private PrePopupPanel panel=new PrePopupPanel( R.layout.preview1);
                @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {


              panel.show(true);
            return true;
        }

...
```

} end the EventsOverly class

```
 class PrePopupPanel {
            View popup;
            boolean isVisible=false;

            PrePopupPanel(int layout) {
              ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)mapView.getParent();

              popup=getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, parent, false);
              popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  hide();
                }
              });

          ImageButton infobtn = (ImageButton)popup.findViewById(R.id.button1);
              infobtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        hide();

// RIGHT HERE I WANT TO CALL A METHOD IN "A" from which this popup was declared


                    }
            });
```

... other methods like show(), hide() etc... copied from someone else

Answer (score 1):

Use an Interface to do this.

-- class A should implement the interface

-- Pass this to PrePopupPanel.

-- call the method through the interface object.

Interface
    package com.demo.interface;

```
public interface ICallHandler {

public void show(String show);

}
```

Class

```
class EventsOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> implements ICallHandler{

         private PrePopupPanel panel=new PrePopupPanel( R.layout.preview1,this);
            @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {


          panel.show(true);
        return true;
    }
```

PrePopupPanel

```
Class PrePopupPanel {
        View popup;
        boolean isVisible=false;
        ICallHandler mHandler;
        PrePopupPanel(int layout, ICallHandler callHandler) {
          mHandler = callHandler;
          ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)mapView.getParent();

          popup=getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, parent, false);
          popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              hide();
            }
          });

      ImageButton infobtn = (ImageButton)popup.findViewById(R.id.button1);
          infobtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    hide();

// RIGHT HERE I WANT TO CALL A METHOD IN "A" from which this popup was declared
                     mHandler.show();

                }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am really sure that this is the answer that I was seeking but I am still trying to wrap my head around it (so new to this). I am reading up on public interface. In the meantime I am wondering where mCallHandler in the PrePopupPanel from the line "mCallHandler mHandler;" is defined and as what? Eclipse offers me a chance to define it as a public interface but I am confused. Regardless, thank you for this key insight about inter object communications.

Comment: Ok. following your instructions, changing the ICallHandler to be mCallHandler, and plugging in all the rest it works! I have seen this question asked several places without an answer, so here it is folks. Now I just need to study this until I completely understand it!

Comment: Sorry.. That is ICallHandler mHandler; Changed now:) Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Your class is inside the other one, you may have access to all member method of your parent.

Comment: sorry my fault... the way I displayed the code snippets did show the one class inside the other. The prepopuppanel is not inside the eventsoverlay.  I have tried to fix that in the way the code is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android Dialog methods.](http://intent.putExtra%28API_FEEDID,%20holder.feedId%29;)

In `onCreateDialog` you can pass a reference to your custom object and trigger any methods you want when user clicks a button. Then anywhere in your activity code call `showDialog()`